# What exactly is C++'s behavior regarding pointers and using functions to initlize them to the heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

Currently having some trouble figuring out why this function will not fully initialize a pointer in the main via a function. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>

void stuff(int * p)
{
    p = new int;
}

int main()
{
    int * p;
    stuff(p);
    *p = 1;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Basically I"m trying to make it so that a function makes the integer pointer access the heap. Right after that, I print it out with the indirect operator and viola, I have my output of one. What's not working is that p is not getting initialized. How exactly can I use a function to initialize that pointer to the heap?

Comment: The pointer `p` in `stuff` is a local variable of `stuff` - it is discarded once the function exits. Your C++ textbook should tell you all about this.

Comment: Assigning to a function's parameter has no effect outside the function. There is nothing special about pointers. (What would you expect `stuff(0)` to do?)

Comment: Pedantic sidenote: C++'s behaviour is defined with the abstract term dynamic memory.  The heap is merely a very common implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null pointer after allocating in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035781/null-pointer-after-allocating-in-function)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you are passing the pointer by value.

So the function `stuff()` gets a copy of the pointer.

```
void stuff(int * p)  // This is a copy of the value you passed in
{
    p = new int;     // Here you modify the local copy.
}                    // The external value of p is unaffected.
```

There are a couple of ways to solve this. But I think the best is to return the value as a result of the function (and not pass it).

```
int* stuff()
{
    return new int;
}
```

Then usage is

```
    p = stuff();
```

But you are probably trying to learn how to get a function to change the value of an object. In this case you need to pass a reference to the object.

```
void stuff(int*& p)  // The & means it is a reference to int*
{
    p = new int;
}
```

Usage:

```
    stuff(p);  // same as your original code.
```

Here you pass a reference to `p` into the function. A reference is another name for an existing object. Any change you make to the reference in the function is mirrored in the object outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be what you're trying to do. The `p` in `stuff` is local, so it will be destroyed at the end of `stuff`. To access the `p` from `main`, you pass a pointer to it into `stuff`. And therefore `stuff` should expect a pointer to a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

void stuff(int ** p)
{
    *p = new int;
}

int main()
{
    int * p;
    stuff(&p);
    *p = 1;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;

    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Preferred alternative: `void stuff(int *& p)
{
    p = new int;
}` and then `stuff(p);`

Comment: `void stuff(int ** p)` is what you would do in `c`. Although it still works in `c++` its preferred to use a reference.

Comment: C++ has native pass-by-reference, there is no reason to use pass-by-pointer as a hack to simulate pass-by-reference

Answer (score -1):

In your implementation function staff takes an unitiallized int* into it's stack and allocates memory for an int. The issue is that p variable is not updated in main function.
There is way to solve this but it is not so elegant.

```
#include <iostream> 

void stuff(int** p) {
    *p = new int;
}

int main()
{
    int * p;
    stuff(&p);
    *p = 1;

    std::cout << *p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This could do what you want.

Comment: As with the other answer, prefer a reference to a pointer: `void stuff(int *& p) { p = new int; }` Less room for errors and fewer modifications to the code. Literally one character is added to the Askers code. That's it.

Comment: It's good to avoid messing with pointers and references like that. A neat solution for your problem could be just something like that:
int* stuff() {
    return new int;
}